# Having issue with hierarchical index Set Behavior

Tags: python, pandas

I have can't figure out this weird behavior I am getting from the hierarchical index I have on a dataframe.  In short, what I am trying to do is very simple; I am trying to figure out whether or not a tuple is in the index of my dataframe.

This is the behavior I **expect**:

```
arrays = [[dt.date(2014,6,4), dt.date(2014,6,4), dt.date(2014,6,21), dt.date(2014,6,21),dt.date(2014,6,13), dt.date(2014,6,13), dt.date(2014,6,7), dt.date(2014,6,7)],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.Series(randn(8), index=index)
print (dt.date(2014,6,4),'one') in s.index
print (dt.date(2014,6,4),'fifty') in s.index
print (dt.date(2014,1,1),'one') in s.index
```

which returns:

```
True 
False 
False
```

Here is what I am **facing**:

```
WeirdIdx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[dt.date(2014,7,4), dt.date(2014,7,5),dt.date(2014,7,6), dt.date(2014,7,7), dt.date(2014,7,8),dt.date(2014,7,9)], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]],labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]],names=[u'day', u'hour'])
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.normal(0,1,5)},index=WeirdIdx)
print type(frame)
print frame.index
print frame
```

yields:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
day         hour
2014-07-04  8   
            8   
            8   
            8   
            8   
                        a
day        hour          
2014-07-04 8     0.335840
           8     0.801193
           8    -0.092492
           8     0.610675
           8    -0.044947
```

and:

```
print (dt.date(2014,7,4),8) in frame.index
print (dt.date(2014,7,4),1) in frame.index
print (dt.date(2014,8,4),1) in frame.index
```

yields:

```
True
True
True
```

and finally:

```
frame.index
```

yields:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[2014-07-04, 2014-07-05, 2014-07-06, 2014-07-07, 2014-07-08, 2014-07-09], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]],
       names=[u'day', u'hour'])
```

One issue is that `(dt.date(2014,8,4),1) in frame.index` **SHOULD** be `False`!

What am I missing here?

Comment: You provided an example for the case that works, but not the case that doesn't.  Can you give a sample DataFrame/Series that shows the unwanted behavior you're seeing?

Comment: The part after here is what I am facing is it.  `print (dt.date(2014,1,4),8) in tmp.index`  should NOT be `True`

Comment: using ``datetime.date`` 'works', but doesn't harness any power of pandas. use ``datetime.datetime`` (or better yet, use ``date_range`` to create your dates.

Comment: @tipanverella: Yes, but what I mean is that the sample data you provide doesn't match with your example that you say doesn't work.  What is the "given dataframe `df`"?

Comment: good point.  But keep in mind that the first example works as expected.  it is the second one that presents the issue.

Comment: I am trying to not use data from my employer.  Shouldn't the construction of the `df` dataframe be irrelevant given the definition `tmp = pd.DataFrame(df.ix[(dt.date(2014,7,4),8),'views'])` ?

Comment: @tipanverella: I can't even get that example to work.  You're calling `DataFrame`, but the output you show looks like a Series.

Comment: @BrenBarn, I will rewrite the question.

Comment: @BrenBarn, I have edited the question.  Take a look when you get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be due to the fact that your MultiIndex is nonunique.  Pandas has strange behavior in this situation, which I would consider a bug.  The problem has nothing to do with dates or even DataFrames at all; it is purely a MultiIndex problem.  Here is a simpler example:

```
WeirdIdx = pandas.MultiIndex(
    levels=[[0], [1]],
    labels=[[0, 0], [0,0]],names=[u'X', u'Y']
)
```

Then any tuple of the right size and types is considered contained in the MultiIndex:

```
>>> (0, 0) in WeirdIdx
True
>>> (1, 0) in WeirdIdx
True
>>> (100, 0) in WeirdIdx
True
>>> (100, 100) in WeirdIdx
True
```

Looking in the source code, I can see how these results arise: indexing falls back to slicing if the MultiIndex is nonunique, and slicing always works even if the values aren't present (just returning a zero-length slice).  But I don't understand why things were implemented that way.

I can't find a bug about this on the pandas bug tracker, although there are a variety of bugs having to do with duplicate MutliIndexes, such as [this bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6501).  Some comments on [this bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2646) suggest the problem should have been fixed in pandas 0.14, but I don't know whether it actually has been fixed, and the bug is still open.  My impression from the various bug reports is that MutliIndexes basically do not work unless they are unique.  I would suggest opening a bug report and/or asking on the pandas mailing list.

Comment: I am running `pandas.__version__` is 0.14, so I guess it has not been fixed.

Comment: How do I cite you on github?

Comment: @tipanverella: You could just link to this question.